# mySQL database folder backup script

Tags: mysql, database-backups

We're backing up our windows based mySQL databases over night by copying the entire mySQL database directory:

```
c$\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5
```

This has caused issues with MySQL, corrupting a table and crashing MySQL.  Not a good idea to back up an active directory. We are looking to turn MySQL off overnight and run the script then.  We also looked at running mysqldump.  Two questions:

What are the drawbacks of taking a folder backup?  It seems like the fastest recovery method

Will running mysqldump on a live server make it unresponsive until the dump has finished?

Comment: If you have two questions, you should ask two questions. Also, these might be a better fit on [server fault](http://serverfault.com/).

Comment: apologies, can we move/migrate this to server fault?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Backing up the real folder which holds the database comes, as you have noticed, with some problems. Files can change while you're copying the folder, which may result in a corrupt backup or (if you lock everything), making it impossible for MySQL to write to (or maybe even read from) the database, which is also extremely very not good (TM).

One method to circument is doing a folder backup via a file system snapshot. I don't know if NTFS supports this, but a quick Google search turned up something called *Shadow Copy*. You might want to look into that.

Then, as pilsetnieks already pointed out, you can run `mysqldump` on InnoDB tables using the `--single-transaction` option.

If you were on Linux, I'd really recommend that you try [Percona Xtrabackup](http://www.percona.com/software/percona-xtrabackup), which has everything you could wish for. They've released an [Alpha version for Windows](http://www.percona.com/downloads/XtraBackup/XtraBackup-1.6/Windows-alpha/). That might be worth a look.

Answer (score 3):

You can run `mysqldump` with the `--single-transaction` option (for InnoDB tables - I hope you're using InnoDB.) That way `mysqldump` doesn't need to lock tables for the duration of the dump and your system will not be completely unresponsive. (Performance might be somewhat impacted but at least it won't be completely dead.)